# My.Computer.Info.OSFullName Crashing Windows XP - .Net 4 Is Installed

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, crash, windows-xp

Does anyone know why calling My.Computer.Info.OSFullName (or .anything) would cause .Net 4 to crash?

Anyone know if it could by Antivirus related, like McAfee software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need some WMI components.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184637(v=vs.80).aspx

Or you need to run your app under full trust.

Comment: After sitting with this issue for a few days, I think this is bigger than just missing WMI. We have been displaying My.Computer.Info.OSFullName in our log files for 2 years and never had and issue, and now we've had two customers contact us about crashes in the last 4 days. It's not normal. Would you happen to know if Microsoft or security software has done anything recently that would block these calls?